# C#: strange rendering in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

[image]

For some reason the labels for "Date From" and "Date To" are rendering strangely on their bottom edges.  See how the datepickers are not rendered correctly because of this.

Anyone know why this is occurring?  It only occurs when I start the app from the exectuable. It doesn't happen in the IDE.

Comment: The labels are too big.  Right-click them, Send To Back for the quick fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the bounds of the `Label` controls are spilling over into the `DateTimePicker` controls. Even when a WinForms control has a transparent background, it is not guaranteed to play nice with other controls in the same container. Try reducing the margins/padding on the labels or select both `DateTimePicker` controls and use the "bring to front" option.

Answer (score 2):

They have a backcolor that matches the form's backcolor.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

- Right-click on the label and choose "Send to Back"
- Right-click on the other control and choose "Bring to Front"
- Make sure the label's `AutoSize` property is set to true and move it up a little until it doesn't show
- Make sure the label's `Padding` property is `0, 0, 0, 0` (zero for each subproperty)

Answer (score 1):

It's frighteningly easy in VS to accidentally change the size and location of controls when manipulating them with the  mouse. You may just have to move/re-size them so they don't overlap. Try moving with the arrow keys or explicitly giving them numeric position and size values.

Answer (score 0):

As mickeyf notes, it's very easy to accidentally move or resize a control.

To reduce the likelihood of this happening, VS allows you to lock controls.  If you right click anywhere on the form, and select "Lock Controls", this will lock **every control on the form**.  I always found this to be too draconian, and rarely used it.

But what I somehow missed until very recently, **each control has a "Locked" property** that can be set individually.  I find this much more convenient - you just lock the controls that tend to be problematic.

For example, I have several forms that have a toolbar at the top, and another control that exactly fills the rest of the form.  It's very easy to accidentally bump this control by a pixel or so, and not realize it.  Now I just lock those controls, which is way more convenient than locking everything.